# why tooltip is not hide on mouseleave event in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am trying to show tooltip on `mouse enter` and hide on `mouse leave`.first i make a simple demo which is working fine.
https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-shannon-4zuij?file=/src/list.js

above code working fine on hover it show's the tooltip and hide on leave.

see same concept i apply on a application.(this code is not working)
https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-liskov-8rvjw?file=/src/App.js

when I hover a item is show the tooltip.but it is not hiding the tooltip when you  leaving the item.something went wrong.

```
const Student = ({students,clickHandler}) => {
    console.log(students,"---ee")
    const [selectedStudent,setSelectedStudent]  = useState(null)

    const onMouseHandler = (student,e)=>{
        student.visibility = true
        setSelectedStudent(student)
    }

    const onMouseLeaveHandler = (student)=>{
        console.log('======',student)
        student.visibility = false
        setSelectedStudent(student)
    }
    return (
        <ul className="student-container">
            {
                students && students.length > 0 ? students.map((student,index)=>{
                    return (
                        <li key={index} onClick={()=>{
                            clickHandler(student)
                        }}
                            onMouseLeave={()=>{
                                onMouseLeaveHandler(student)
                            }}
                            onMouseEnter={(e)=>{
                            onMouseHandler(student,e)
                        }} style={{position:'relative'}}>
                        <a><span>{student.name}</span></a>
                            {student.visibility? <ToolTip showToolTip={student.visibility} selectedStudent={selectedStudent}/>:null}
                        </li>
                    )
                }):null
            }
        </ul>
    );
};

export default Student;
```

Step too reproduce

1. Hover on first item `Raj`
2. and then try to hover `sameer`.both tooltip will display.I want only one tooltip will be display which is hovered.

`I want my handlers should be in my functional component . I don't want to move these handler to parent component and pass handler as a props`

Comment: Your demo does not seem to properly work. I think the problem is that you're mutating the props, you should only change the state to reflect which student is hovered on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your demo it's also not work well, - one hide only when open another.
when you set `student.visibility` you not set state, so nothing has rerendered.

Then when you call `setSelectedStudent` you pass there just the same referance as was before, since it's the same object, so the state not changed, and again - nothing got rerendered.

What you have to do is pass the updated student in a new variable. like so:

```
setSelectedStudent({...student})
```

Then all should work